# Solr CapitalizationFilterFactory not working

Tags: solr, filtering, filterfactory

I am a complete noob when it comes to solr, this is my first configuration and I am having issues getting solr data to be filtered properly. We are using solr 4.0, the 09-21-2011 snapshot. What I want is to capitalize the first letter of each word in various fields.  The data we index will have data like 'name' = 'STAR WARS'. What i want is when I query the data that the name should come back as 'Star Wars' but is comes back as 'STAR WARS'

Here is my setup

```
<fieldType name="text_capital" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>                
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CapitalizationFilterFactory" onlyFirstWord="false" okPrefix="CVS"/>         
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">                      
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CapitalizationFilterFactory" onlyFirstWord="false" okPrefix="CVS"/>                
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And here is the field mapping

```
<field name="name" type="text_capital" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Now when i look at the analyzer everything looks fine for both query and index it hits the tokenizer and all the filters properly, but when i run a query results come back with the name as all caps. I feel like i am missing something obvious here.

Thanks,

-zach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you refer as "coming back" is the *stored* value which is *always* the verbatim value you fed to Solr when indexing. Tokenizers, filters, etc, affect the *indexed* value which is used when searching (and the query terms). It's up to you to transform the stored value you get back into the form you want.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, that makes sense, but then this setup should index the data in the format that i want. right?

Comment: @zlegein: index, yes, but stored values are separate.